# How to send text within a webtable cell using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to send value "100" in to Position `(row: 2, column 3)` of Table, here:

https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/13800848854767

With this code below, could you tell me, what's wrong?

Code:

```
driver.get("https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/13800848854767");
List<WebElement> inputTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='var_a_EXL']//tbody//tr"));
System.out.println(inputTable.size());
List<WebElement> columns;
for (int rows = 0; rows < inputTable.size(); rows++) {
    if (rows == 2) {
        columns = inputTable.get(rows).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                columns.get(i).clear();
                columns.get(i).sendKeys("100");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looping logic is correct, but your code produce this error:

> `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state`

You need to `click` first before taking the next action on that element to become an editable element, and you must use the [**`Actions`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class to interact with it:

```
driver.get("https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/13800848854767");
List<WebElement> inputTable = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='var_a_EXL']//tbody//tr")));
System.out.println(inputTable.size());
List<WebElement> columns;
for (int rows = 0; rows < inputTable.size(); rows++) {
    if (rows == 2) {
        columns = inputTable.get(rows).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                WebElement target = columns.get(i);
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                actions.moveToElement(target)
                    .click(target)
                    .sendKeys("100")
                    .build()
                    .perform();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I also added `WebDriverWait` to the above code.

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

By the way with this xpath `//*[@id='var_a_EXL']//tbody//tr[3]//td[4]` there is a simpler way instead of using looping above:

```
driver.get("https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/13800848854767");
WebElement target = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='var_a_EXL']//tbody//tr[3]//td[4]")));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(target)
    .click(target)
    .sendKeys("100")
    .build()
    .perform();
```

Or use the following css selector to better locate element:

```
By.cssSelector("#var_a_EXL tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(4)")
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your answer. It work for me. The code [List<WebElement> inputTable = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[@id='var_a_EXL']//tbody//tr")));] is neu for me, but i gonna try to understand and learn it rightnow :)

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @frianH's answer, The reason why your code isn't working is because `.clear()` works only if the element is a text entry element. Text entry elements are INPUT and TEXTAREA which is not the scenario in your case

Here's a simpler way using a JSExecutor

```
    List<WebElement> inputTable = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='var_a_EXL']//tbody//tr"));
    System.out.println(inputTable.size());
    List<WebElement> columns;
    int rowss = 3;
    int columnss = 3;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < inputTable.size(); rows++) {
        if (rows == rowss) {
            columns = inputTable.get(rows).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            System.out.println(columns.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
                if (i == columnss) {
                    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                    js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = '300'", columns.get(i));
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for yor answer. It doesn't work with this code: js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = '300'", columns.get(i)); But the solution is interessting. I will analyze it for my case

Comment: jeez, I just tried this code and its working flawlessly, what error are you getting ? Here's my complete code [link](https://pastebin.com/Ke2BE2z1)

Comment: Hi, my scope is to send a value (for example: 100) to the position (row x, column y) of the Table. But with your code i become the actual text of position (row x, column y)

Comment: Fair enough, I have updated the code and called out the variables for positions outside so you can update anywhere now

Comment: Ah, Ok. Its working fine. with your solution i think i can creat a small function to position any node of a table and later in Main i can do anythings with it. Very fine. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned about the error you are facing. Mentioning the error would have helped us to construct a more canonical answer. Possibly you are facing `InvalidElementStateException` as you are trying to invoke `clear()` on a `<td>` element.

However, to send the character string **100** into position (row: 2, column z) of table you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/13800848854767");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/span[@id='var_a_EXL_2_3C']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/input[@id='var_a_EXL_2_3_input']"))).sendKeys("100");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: function_table]

---

### Row and Column number as variables

Considering `row` and `column` number as variables:

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/13800848854767");
  int row = 2;
  int column = 3;
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/span[contains(@id, '"+String.valueOf(row)+"') and contains(@id, '"+String.valueOf(column)+"')]"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td/input[contains(@id, '"+String.valueOf(row)+"') and contains(@id, '"+String.valueOf(column)+"')]"))).sendKeys("100");
  ```

Comment: Yes, i worked with (TypeScript and Protractor) and i can understand it. But in Java is this for me still new. Thank you for your help. I'm going to lern it :)